# Django e-mail template error

Tags: python, django, email

I'm trying to setup a HTML template that takes in some field forms for the subject header, and for part of the content.

**views.py**

```
if len(recipient) > 0:
   messages.success(request, "Receipt sent successfully!")

   subject = "Your Booking Reference: "
   to = [recipient]
   from_email = 'orders@demo.net'

   template = get_template('booking/email/booking_reference.html')

   message = EmailMessage(subject, template, from_email, ['test@test.com'])
   message.content_subtype = 'html'
   message.send()

   return HttpResponse("Sent!")            
else:
   return index(request)
```

Whenever I request an email to be sent, I get the following error:
`'Template' object has no attribute 'encode'`

If I comment out `message.content_subtype = 'html'`, I get the desired HttpResponse, but with no e-mail sent. I've added this setting to my `settings.py` file so that all e-mails get output to the console, but nothing is displayed

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: That is because the console expects the content type to be html. It is recommended to leave the content_subtype setting to the default (which is "text/plain")

Comment: Same error when I change it to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think the problem is that you don't add a context in your template so try this:

```
if len(recipient) > 0:
    messages.success(request, "Receipt sent successfully!")
    subject = "Your Booking Reference: "
    to = [recipient]
    from_email = 'orders@demo.net'

    template = loader.get_template('booking/email/booking_reference.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, locals())
    template = template.render(context)
    message = EmailMessage(subject, template, from_email, ['test@test.com'])
    message.content_subtype = 'html'
    message.send(True)

    return HttpResponse("Sent!")            
else:
    return index(request)
```

Comment: Perfect! THANK YOU, all worked perfectly except I had to exclude the loader, as I've already imported the function!

Answer (score 1):

Try to write this :

```
message = EmailMultiAlternatives (subject, template, from_email, [test@test.com])
message.attach_alternative(template, "text/html")
```

Comment: Ok try to write message.send(True)